# How to access the jar placed inside lib\ext directory in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, classloader

I've made a jar library and places it inside jdk and jre's ext directory to check for **installed extension** scenario in Java.

Now when I a trying to create a Java project in eclipse and try to use the jar files classes or use the library, I am not able to access but those jar files are visible under Java PRoject jre system library in ECLIPSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably will have to specifically reference the jar in Eclipse.  The colleciton of JARs that come with the JRE are also included in the manifest file so that the runtime knows which files to request be loaded.  Since your jar is not in the manifest, it will not be loaded automatically.

An alternative might be to repackage a JRE with an updated manifest that refers to your extension jar.

Comment: in the directory , where actually I can look for the manifest file as I know manifest file should be the part of a jar file , so is it like a parent jar so called rt.jar consists this manifest file including all other child or subjars files

Comment: Incorrect: There is no "manifest file" that would list extensions. "Any JAR file in the lib/ext of the JRE directory is automatically treated by the runtime environment as an extension." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html

Answer (score 2):

1. Are the extension classes loaded when you run something outside of Eclipse? For example you can try the following command in a terminal to check if a class from the extension can be found:

   ```
   javap name.of.ExtensionClass
   ```
2. When you run your program from Eclipse, are you sure that you use the JRE that has the extension installed?

Comment: Yes I am sure about my jre version and as I mentioned, I am able to see the loaded jar in the jre library in ECLIPSE itself, so logically its already loaded or part of jre library but accessing is the issue

Comment: Did you check that classes from the extension can be loaded?

Comment: actually javap command is not responding , might be some issue with CLASS_PATH as I mostly/always use eclipse , so didn't know the way to sort it out

Comment: If you had the .jar file in the correct `ext` directory `javap` would respond with a summary of what's in the class. CLASSPATH has nothing to with it, as the extension-loading mechanism has precedence. See e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/load.html

Answer (score 0):

After adding to JAVA_HOME/lib/ext file or java.ext.dirs system property,
Don't Run the jar file ,it won't.
but Run the class with package name ,it will.